# Using multiple servers for a single sharepoint site

Tags: replication

We have a global infrastructure and I have been getting complaints of load times taking too long for our users that are in far off countries trying to visit sharepoint sites.

Right now our whole farm is < 10 sites, and not too terribly huge.

I have been searching for ways to be able to create a second sharepoint server(win2k3) and have them replicate to each other.

I am mostly finding third party software for being able to replicate. And that mostly says 2010.

I was wondering if anyone here has had any experience in mirroring SQL (2005) databases and configuring WSS 3.0 to replicate between 2 servers.

I imagine there is a way to do this effectively.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of good planning articles on TechNet that you should start by reading:

[Global deployment of multiple farms (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg441257)
[Configure availability by using SQL Server database mirroring (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207314.aspx)